# Passing id in URL to a modal

Tags: php, html, css, simplemodal

I have a modal with an ID called `modal_act_cat` so I have anohter modal with a table. I want to pass the id from the table to the modal by clicking the field. My line code to go to the modal is (which opens the modal but with the fields empty):

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='#modal_act_cat name='cat_nombre_id'>" . $row['cat_nombre_id'] . "</a></td>
```

but if I add parameters to the URL in `href`, the modal does not show.

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='#modal_act_cat?cat_nombre_id=" . $row['cat_nombre_id'] . "' name='cat_nombre_id'>" . $row['cat_nombre_id'] . "</a></td>
```

See my modal below that I'm trying to get the `cat_nombre_id` to show the results.

```
  <div class="modal_container" id="modal_act_cat">
    <div class="modal">
      <a href="index.php" class="close">+</a>
      <span class="modal_heading">Actualizar categoría</span>
      <a href="#buscar_cat" class="logo">
        <i class="icon ion-md-search"></i>
      </a>
      <form class="form_crear_cat" action="crear_cat.php" method="POST">
        <?php
        require("conn.php");
        if(isset($_GET['cat_nombre_id'])){
          $cat_nombre_id = $_GET['cat_nombre_id'];
          $query = "SELECT * FROM categorias WHERE cat_nombre_id = '$cat_nombre_id'";
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
            <input type="text" id="cc1" name="cat_nombre_id" value="" placeholder="Nombre de la Categoría" required><?php echo $row['cat_nombre_id']; ?></input>
            <input type="text" name="supCat_nombre_id" value="" placeholder="Nombre de la Super Categoría" required><?php echo $row['supCat_nombre_id']; ?></input>
            <textarea name="cat_descripcion" rows="3" placeholder="Descripción de la Categoría"><?php echo $row['cat_descripcion']; ?></textarea>
            <?php
          }
        }
        ?>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using javascript modal and if it is true you should pass the id using javascript

```
echo "<tr><td><a href='#modal_act_cat" data-id='".$row['cat_nombre_id']."' name='cat_nombre_id'>" . $row['cat_nombre_id'] . "</a></td>
```

and then rest of modal content should be ajax based.